# How to rename a subset of columns based on offset/index and variable range?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with student test data. The data provided is in a new format and I need to align it with the older format for an existing BI application. Where a range of columns used to contain questions numbers, the column name now contains the correct answer (this includes duplicate column names as imported form the source XLSX - see the image below). Different year levels have a different number of questions (so the "Total" column is not fixed. I need to rename the answer columns back to the sequential question numbers starting at 1. What is the best way to achieve this?

NB the sample df is not quite right as there are duplicate column names as the column name represents the correct answer. I cannot provide a sample df without importing it from a CSV/XLSX.

Updated with some sample df data:

```html
data = {
        'StudentID': [10, 11, 12, 13],
        'Year' : [2021,2021,2021,2021],
        'TestName': ['Math83', 'Math83','Math83','Math83'],
        'A' : ['C','A','C','B'],
        'B' : ['D','C','C','C'],
        'C' : ['D','D','C','D'],
        'D' : ['B','C','C','C'],
        'Total': [5,4,3,5,],
        'Score': [3,3,4,2,],
        'Error': [1,2,1,1]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `set_axis()`

```
cols = df.columns
tn = cols.get_loc('TestName')+1
total = cols.get_loc('Total')

(df.set_axis(cols[:tn].tolist() + 
             list(range(1,len(df.columns[tn:total+1]))) + 
             cols[total:].tolist(),axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   StudentID  Year TestName  1  2  3  4  Total  Score  Error
0         10  2021   Math83  C  D  D  B      5      3      1
1         11  2021   Math83  A  C  D  C      4      3      2
2         12  2021   Math83  C  C  C  C      3      4      1
3         13  2021   Math83  B  C  D  C      5      2      1
```

Comment: The issue is that the number of columns is not fixed, so `[3:9]` won't work for all cases.

Comment: just edited using `get_loc()`

Comment: Thanks rhug123, the enumerate works a treat (never used that before), but the whole line returns a {NameError}name 'df' is not defined. I think this is caused by the duplicate column names. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: I believe I have updated the solution to fix this issue

Comment: Pure genius. Works a treat.